# Доступ к папке проекта

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Можно ли как-то взять объект из папки проекта? Не считая класс Resources и все что с ним связано, к примеру в папке Assets есть префаб куба Cube, можно ли как-то получить доступ к этому префабу не передавая его в кеш? т.е. есть путь и по нему достать объект?

Comment: уточните вы хотите это делать в редакторе или в игре?

Comment: в игре и в редакторе, но из кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ можно поделить на 2 части - про редактор и про игру.

### Игра

*Все перечисленные здесь возможности будут работать и в редакторе.*

- можете работать с ресурсами, которые располагаются в [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html). Отсюда можно только считывать(загружать) файлы. При сборке проекта, все ресурсы, находящиеся в этих папках (их может быть сколько угодно с таким названием) собираются в единый бинарный ассет. Так что в редакторе Resources представляет собой виртуальную папку.
- можно работать с файлами из [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html). Хороший туториал можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.raywenderlich.com/479-using-streaming-assets-in-unity). Можно только читать.
- можно работать с [Application.presistanDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) Можно читать и писать файлы и папки. Представляет собой внешнее хранилище приложения. На разных платформах это хранилище представляет собой различные пути, однако API для работы с ним одинаковое.

Касаемо вашего вопроса про префаб, лежащий в `Assets/...`, в игре у вас не получится получить доступ до этого файла, если он не лежит в `Resources`, либо `StreamingAssets`, либо в `Application.presistanDataPath`.

### Редактор

*Все, перечисленное для игры будет работать также и в редакторе.*

- можно работать с классом [AssetDataBase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html), который позволяет читать, писать, удалять, добавлять любые файлы в проект Unity. Это касается не только префабов, но будет работать и для скриптов (в случае, если вы захотите работать с кодогенерацией из редактора, это пожалуй, единственное возможное решение).

Касаемо вашего вопроса про префаб, лежащий в `Assets/...` в редакторе, можно использовать [AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html), который загружает ассет именно по пути в проекту.